# grep char followed by anything containing specific other characters

Tags: regex, bash, shell, grep, regex-lookarounds

I would like to use grep to search a directory (/bin) for anything starting with a specific character and followed by any string containing one of two other specific characters. In my case I want every file starting with a 'g' and contain the letters 'e' or 'n'. I have tried many variations of "ls /bin | grep '^g'".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
ls /bin | grep '^g.*[en]'
```

Comment: Parsing `ls` output isn't the best thing to do: [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls command](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: @codeforester Guys, we really should stop this _don't parse ls_ thing. While me completly agree with the reasons (and im pretty sure that Toto know this also), myself using the `ls | some_command` is daily command-line work often. (Of course, will never use it in scripts but it is perfectly acceptable in _direct terminal work_. Commenting every `ls` **answer** with such link, is just a bugging...  (just IMHO) ;(

Comment: I was also able to do it (the hard way) with "ls /bin | grep -P '^g(?=.[e|n])'" . Also, thanks for the link!

Answer (score 1):

With `find` you can do:

```
find /bin -regex '/bin/g.*[en].*'
```